# Grails addTo* slowly performance with event

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

In my Grails App i'm using some technologies very excited but recently i'm having some problems with performance, i will describe my cenario:

- One table with 4M+ entires;
- I'm using the Event Bus API;
- Grails 2.2.3;
- MySQL DB;

When the client create new room, some Alloc is created too.

```
pseudo-code:
    Room {
      hasMany = aloccs: Alloc
    }
```

Look this code (is not the real code, but with same equality):

```
@Listener(topic="topicAlocCreator")
def alocCreator(EventMessage<Long> message) {

    LocalDate start = new DateTime().toLocalDate()
    LocalDate end = new DateTime().plusYears(2).plusMonths(6).toLocalDate()
    LocalDate tmp = start


    Room room = Room.get(message.data)
    List channels = Channel.list
    while(tmp.compareTo(end) <= 0) {
        for(channel in channels) {
            room.addToAlocs(new Aloc(0, 0, tmp.toDate(), channel))
        }
        tmp = tmp.plusDays(1)
    }

    //end of method
}
```

This codes works fine, but it generated a lot of alloc objects and put it in a hibernate session.

What it's the correct way to do this job, using flush? Batch? 
- The call to method is assync.

this codes was work fine until (07/14) but during this days it is very slow, something like 1.30 min to insert 10K of alloc in the database;

Thanks a lot for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `allocs` is a `Set` (default Grails collection type when you define a `hasMany` relationship), Grails has to load the whole collection into memory before the insert can happen in order to guarantee uniqueness.

Take a look at Bert Beckwith's [presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/GORM-Performance) on the performance implications of using GORM collections.

I think you have a couple of options. You could dispense with the collection reference entirely, and just define your classes like this:

```
class Alloc {
    Room room
}

class Room {
    //no reference child Allocs
}
```

Alternatively, you could define your `allocs` collection as a bag:

```
class Alloc {
    static belongsTo = [room: Room]
}

class Room {
    Collection allocs
    static hasMany = [allocs: Alloc]
}
```

in this case there's no need for the uniqueness check and the `addTo...` method won't need to load every `Alloc` instance into memory. You will, however, then be responsible for maintaining uniqueness yourself...

[Reference](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#sets,ListsAndMaps)

Comment: I'm using de List, and the hibernate create a alloc_idx in my database, using Collection is more performatic then?

Comment: Definitely not better (the entire collection is unnecessarily loaded from the database regardless of collection type) and probably worse actually. With a Set only uniqueness is guaranteed, so Hibernate detects added and deleted instances in the Set and makes the corresponding individual database updates. That additional column is used to track the order within the List, and if you turn on SQL logging you'll see that Hibernate will delete all instances and re-insert them when the order changes rather than updating the idx column.

Comment: It turns out that using Bags doesn't fix the problem and can make things work - I wrote up some findings in [this blog post](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1029)

Comment: Thanks @BurtBeckwith and @ rcgeorge23.

Comment: Sorry, typo in previous comment, should read "can make things _worse_"